# Is there a way to perform actions every time I call library(package) in R?

Tags: r, r-package

I've already learned that including a script "**zzz.R**" in my R package with a .onAttach function provides me performing actions every time I load an R package for the first time. The package name is **utils_department**.

The thing is: if I do not detach the package, it is not possible to go for `library(utils_department)` for the 2nd time and have the same actions as a result.

Here are my functions:

```
load_useful_objects <- function(){
  ex_number <<- 2
  ex_string <<- "test"
}

.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname){
  packageStartupMessage("Welcome to the package utils_department! Please report any bugs or improvement ideas to the package maintainer.\n")
  packageStartupMessage("Loading useful objects into the global environment...")
  load_useful_objects()
}
```

My goal is: running a function that loads useful objects into the global environment every time that `library(utils_department)` is run and perform the same actions even if the package was already loaded (without having to detach it).

Is it possible?

Comment: A package is only attached once unless you explicitly detach it, that's an *efficiency*: don't do things (like populate the namespace, search path, etc) if it's already been done once. I suggest you create a function in your package (exported or otherwise) that does what you want, then call that function in `.onAttach` and whenever you want its side-effects re-done.

Comment: Just add a couple of lines to `library`'s body to check for the attached-status of the package in question and detach it if necessary. You might also want to change `require` in the same manner.

Comment: @r2evans That's what was done in `.onAttach`: it calls function `load_useful_objects` (which does what I want). I didn't understand how I can have the side-effects re-done if it was already done for the first time I ran `library` whitout detaching.

Comment: I have this exact challenge, if you find an answer I'd love to know